# Relative path configuration in appsettings.json in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-configuration

For sake of simplicity lets say we have the following structure of configuration files where I load all of them:

```
c:\apps\myapp\appsettings.json
c:\apps\appsettings.json
c:\appsettings.json
```

The configuration "schema" looks like this:

```json
{
  "logPath": "c:\\apps\\logs"
}
```

Instead of giving absolute path of log folder, I would like to give relative one like `.\\logs` where `.` would be current configuration file. While debugging I discovered that `IConfigurationRoot` contains all those configuration sources (in this case `JsonConfigurationSource`) which contains path to configuration file, but I didn't find any way how to get ConfigurationSource for specific key. So Something like `IConfigurationRoot.GetConfigurationSource(string key)`.

Is there any way how to get configuration source for specific key? Or maybe some other way to use relative paths?